# Difference between npm jasmine and jasmine-core packages

Tags: npm, jasmine

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-core said it contains core files only. Why so many projects use core-files only instead of complete files? Such as https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason the `jasmine` repo has so many more downloads is because all the language-specific Jasmine modules/packages depend on it. For example, when I added the jasmine gem to my Rails app, it installed both `jasmine-gem` and `jasmine-core`.

The naming is a bit confusing. Basically, they are trying to direct npm users to the `jasmine-npm` module that adds Node.js-specific features to Jasmine.

`jasmine-core` on npm points to the `jasmine` repository, which has the main Jasmine code. It's used in multiple types of projects, including Ruby, Node, and Python.

`jasmine` on npm points to the `jasmine-npm` repository, and it depends upon the code in the `jasmine` repository. Its README says: "This module allows you to run Jasmine specs for your Node.js code. The output will be displayed in your terminal by default."

[Comparing jasmine vs. jasmine-core vs. jasmine-node vs. mocha](https://npmcompare.com/compare/jasmine,jasmine-core,jasmine-node,mocha)